# Join 3 tables in MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to show some columns in different tables and it didn't work

Here is my code :

```
select 
  id_reciept, id_member , member_name, 
  id_product, product_name, qty, price 
from member 
cross join  product 
cross join transaction;
```

in table transaction there is `id, reciept`

and in member table there is `id_member,member_name`

and product table there is `id_product,product_name,qty,price`

can anyone help me? thankyou so much

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.  You need conditions that connect the tables.

Comment: MySQL 2012??? Do you mean SQLServer 2012?? It can be relevant to get these right as the syntax is not always the same

Comment: yups its SQLServer 2012,and i dont have any idea about this thing

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/

Answer (score 0):

You can not join these tables. In order to join tables it must have connection conditions.
For exemple to join table transaction with member table, transaction need to have member_id or another connection field that bouth tables have.

```
Select t.*, m.*, p.* From transactions t Join member m On m.member_id = t.member_id Join product p On p.product_id = t.product_id
```

Comment: i already add member id,product id at transaction table
so how can i show those

Comment: Select t.*, m.*, p.*
From transactions t
Join member m On m.member_id = t.member_id
Join product p On p.product_id = t.product_id